# Try catch in java doesn't work

Tags: java, jxl

```
try {
    for(int j = 0; j<cellCountForCustomers-1; j++, customerRow++) {

        Cell c2 = sheetForGroups.getCell(customerColumn, customerRow);    
        String clientUserID = c2.getContents();        
        if(c2.getType() == CellType.EMPTY){
            customerColumn = 0;
            break;
        }    

        driver.findElement(By.id("clientuserid1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("clientuserid1")).sendKeys(clientUserID);
        driver.findElement(By.id("add")).click();    
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {    
    e.printStackTrace();    
}
```

I'm trying to read an excel file using the jxl extension. Somehow, when the excel file ends and there are no more cells further, it does not catch the index out of bounds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't catch the exception? Is the execution stopping?

Comment: @UmaKanth it's already after try , may be you should check the braces .

Comment: @Denise Starker are you sure it is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, might be some other super of thisis thrown

Comment: Why don't you catch `Exception e` and check whether you getting any exception? If there is any exception, check what it is.

Comment: Yes, the execution stops. It says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14

Comment: Possibly exception is other than `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I think that a missing part is where and how `customerRow` is initialized...

Comment: I tried catch Exception e, but it still doesn't catch it.

Comment: @UmaKanth that's his style of writing a while loop :P

Comment: Does the execution stop or is the exception printed. Since you have put e.printStackTrace(), the exception would be printed out. That doesn't mean that the exception is not caught. Can you put a System.out in the catch and check if that is printed out?

Comment: @DeniseStarker you should post a full stacktrace and show us which line in your program triggered it. My guess is that `sheetForGroups.getCell(customerColumn, customerRow)` is the reason.

Answer (score -2):

```
          try
         {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cood in try", 1).show();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
              Toast.makeText(context, "cood in catch", 1).show();
         }
```

Comment: this sorce for android    //// این سورس برای آندرویده البته تو جاوا هم خروجی میده